# Streaming the Desktop with VLC on Win7 x64

Tags: streaming, desktop, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC 1.1.0 and Win7 x64 to Stream my Desktop to another Computer. 
At The moment I'm using this code to start VLC on the Server:

```
vlc screen:// :screen-fps=30 :screen-caching=100 --sout 
#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,acodec=mpga,ab=256,scale=1,
width=1280,height=800}:duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=192.168.2.3,port=5004,mux=ts},
dst=display} :sout-rtp-sap :sout-rtp-name=Glory :sout-standard-sap 
:sout-standard-name=Glory :sout-standard-group=Movie :sout-all :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

192.168.2.3 is the destination(client), where I call the stream

At the Client I call

```
vlc rtp://@:5004
```

This Stream generates about 5 MBit/s permanent traffic.

Why is the traffic so high? The Server is used for presentations and so the picture is often the same. Why are not only the changes of the picture send?
Any idea to improve the codec, resolution , .... ?
On the videolan homepage http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html
I read that

Examples of needed bandwidth are:

```
0.5 to 4 Mbit/s for a MPEG-4 stream,
3 to 4 Mbit/s for an MPEG-2 stream read from a satellite card, a digital television card or a MPEG-2 encoding card,
6 to 9 Mbit/s for a DVD
```

My quality is not so high-> so It should need about 2 Mbit/s

Thanks To every help

Answer (score 0):

Just for video your using vb=4096... 4Mb/s plus audio ab=256... 256Kb/s . try reducing the size of the video to 2048, audio can be lower also or reducing the fps to below 30 fps.